# Object with the same key already exists in ObjectStateManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework

I am trying to implement the following code but I keep getting the following error.

> An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The existing object is in the Unchanged state. An object can only be added to the ObjectStateManager again if it is in the added state.

```
     Function Create(lkmeasure As LkMeasure, ByVal oForm As FormCollection) As ActionResult
        Dim ObjectiveList As New List(Of String)
        Try
            If ModelState.IsValid Then

                If Not DirectCast(Session("LoggedInUser"), SecurityUser).SecurityRole.RoleName.ToLower.Equals(cCommon.UserRole.Administrator.ToString.ToLower()) Then
                    lkmeasure.AgencyID = DirectCast(Session("LoggedInUser"), SecurityUser).AgencyID
                End If

                lkmeasure.StatusID = Convert.ToInt16(oForm("MeasureStatus").ToString())

                If Not oForm("PerformanceObjectives") Is Nothing AndAlso oForm("PerformanceObjectives").Length > 0 Then
                    'If Convert.ToInt16(oForm("PerformanceObjectives").ToString()).Equals(0) Then
                    '    lkmeasure.ObjectiveID = 0
                    'Else
                    'lkmeasure.ObjectiveID = Convert.ToInt16(oForm("PerformanceObjectives").ToString())
                    ObjectiveList = oForm("PerformanceObjectives").ToString().Split(",").ToList()
                    'End If
                End If
                lkmeasure.MeasureCreateDate = DateTime.Now
                lkmeasure.MeasureUpdateDate = DateTime.Now
                'Dim lkMeasureObjList As New List(Of LkMeasure)

                For Each obj In ObjectiveList
                    Dim lkmeasureobj As New LkMeasure
                    lkmeasureobj = lkmeasure
                    lkmeasureobj.MeasureCreateDate = DateTime.Now
                    lkmeasureobj.MeasureUpdateDate = DateTime.Now
                    lkmeasureobj.ObjectiveID = Convert.ToInt16(obj)
                    db.LkMeasures.AddObject(lkmeasureobj)
                    db.SaveChanges()
                    lkmeasureobj = Nothing
                Next


                Return RedirectToAction("Index")
            End If

            Call CreateViewBag()
            Return View(lkmeasure)
        Catch ex As Exception

            Return Nothing
        End Try


    End Function
```

I have made the object nothing but still it says object is added.

Comment: It means that In your DBContext exist another entity with the same key. Which property is your key?

Comment: There is an measureid in the lkmeasure object which is the key

Comment: How do you initialize MeasureID  ? Is an identity field in your database? You get this error at the first loop? The second... ?

Comment: I am getting an model object back from the view. I have a list box where the user selects more than one objective id value. So i am trying to add an seperate object for each of the selected objective id values. The first loop the object gets inserted in second loop i get this error.

Comment: How do you set the value of your primary key? Is it a identity field from database?

Comment: I have included the full function for reference. Please suggest if i missed anything.

Comment: To help you I need to know how do you set value to primary key, when is inserted. Is a calculated property, it's a identity column in your database? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Comment: Yes the primary key is an identity column in database

Comment: I don't know why but It seems that In the first iteration of your loop, the value of your primary key is not retrieved from database. Then the second iteration crash because in the DBContext exists two objects LkMeasure with the same primary key value. Is the a setter in MesaureID ?

Comment: Yes MeasureId is the primary key

Comment: But why would it pick up a value from database when all i am trying to do is to add an object with values ?

Comment: When you add an Object to your DBContext, its primary key has to be unique, if not it throws your error. If you add two LkMeause instance, both with MesaureID value set 0, it will throw this error.

Comment: ok i tried to initialize the the MeasureID value by the following statement but i still get the same error, do i need to change only the primary key or even the foreign keys too ? lkmeasureobj.MeasureID = Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()

Comment: Because of this line, you are trying to add the same instance on each iteration of the loop: `lkmeasureobj = lkmeasure`.  After the first time through the loop, it has already been added, so you can't do `AddObject` again.  The line before is `Dim lkmeasureobj As New LkMeasure`, but this new instance is not used.  I'm not sure what your intention is there.

Comment: Hi @Mark What i am trying to do is I have an object with certain information, i am creating a new object copying the info from the existing object changing certain values and inserting the object into DB using DBcontext. So the idea is create a new object, copy values from previous object (instead of using form collection to fill the details everytime) change few values and put it in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a new `LkMeasure` for each value in `ObjectiveList` then try something like the following:

```
For Each obj In ObjectiveList
    Dim lkmeasureobj As New LkMeasure
    ' Copy values from your "prototype" lkmeasure instance
    lkmeasureobj.AgencyID = lkmeasure.AgencyID
    lkmeasureobj.StatusID = lkmeasure.StatusID
    lkmeasureobj.MeasureCreateDate = DateTime.Now
    lkmeasureobj.MeasureUpdateDate = DateTime.Now
    lkmeasureobj.ObjectiveID = Convert.ToInt16(obj)
    db.LkMeasures.AddObject(lkmeasureobj)
Next
' Only save once, outside of the loop
db.SaveChanges()
```